# QSytemTrayIcon does not show up in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, ubuntu-12.04, system-tray

I have created a program that runs in the background using PyQt4. A system tray icon is created in a separate thread that allows me to interact with the main program, after its creation and placement in the tray. I have never had a problem with this before in Ubuntu 10.04. However, I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04, and for some reason there is not even a trace of the QSystemTrayIcon I desire. Can anyone clue me in as to what exactly is going on here? I have looked for posts about my question on AskUbuntu and SO, but can't seem to find anything in the database that matches my problem. I have included only portions of my code which I think are relevant, but will provide more information if necessary.

EDIT: I have already modified the tray panel white-list in Ubuntu, and set it to `['all']`, so I was able to identify that as not being a problem.

Relevant piece of code:

```
class notify(threading.Thread, QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, process, iconMain, iconNew, parent=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, iconMain, parent)

        self.menu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)
        self.menuNew = QtGui.QMenu(parent)

        viewAdsAction = self.menu.addAction("View Ads")
        textModeAction = self.menu.addAction("Text-Mode")
        exitAction = self.menu.addAction("Exit")
        textModeActionNew = self.menuNew.addAction("PC-Mode")
        exitActionNew = self.menuNew.addAction("Exit")

        self.iconMain = iconMain
        self.iconNew = iconNew
        self.setContextMenu(self.menu)
        self.process = process
        self.textMode = False
```

Execution in main():

```
def main():
    os.chdir(os.getenv("HOME") + "/.Phones")
    beginMain = mainProgram()
    beginMain.start()
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()

    notifications = notify(beginMain, QtGui.QIcon("icon-58x58.xpm"), QtGui.QIcon("notify.xpm"), w)
    notifications.show()
    notifications.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `class notify(threading.Thread, QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon)` this looks to me very strange. Are you sure you want to go on with this - inheriting from two absolutely different classes?

Comment: @warwaruk, I was trying to run a thread that does a check through infinite loop, and am also using QSystemTrayIcon to interact with that loop. It seems to be working okay... no problems yet.

Comment: I think it's risky, because the parent classes are not implemented by you, they are very complex, and you could have attribute conflicts, especially when you are adding your own. At some point you could have hard traceable problems.

Comment: It would be nice to ask this as a separate question - to see what other people think.

Comment: Thank you for your comments/advice warwaruk, I will keep this in mind when when I develop in the future. Maybe I will ask this question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue, the resolution was garbage. Apparently Qt and Unity do not get along with certain resolutions, I was running a 58x58 scaled icon. I scaled it down to 48x48, and now the system tray icon is visible, and working correctly with my program.